# What is the purpose of & a value to itself?

Tags: javascript

I know about boolean logic. However, this question pertains to a specific use case of JS. A `&` is used with the same variable on both sides.

In the code snippet below, what is the reason for `hash = hash & hash`?

```
const hash =(string) => {
  //set variable hash as 0
  var hash = 0;
  // if the length of the string is 0, return 0
  if (string.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0 ;i<string.length ; i++)
  {
    ch = string.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + ch;
    hash = hash & hash;
  }
  return hash;
 };
```

Comment: Also, here's a CodeSandbox app for visualizing bitwise operations: https://7io9he.csb.app/

Comment: "What is the purpose of & a value to itself?" the same as `|0` or `>>0`. It (ab)uses a side-effect of bit-operations in JS

Comment: @Thomas if you don't know a dupe, you should post an answer explaining that side-effect for those who aren't aware of it

Comment: All these operations seem to result in no op. What is the side-effect?